# C Compiler error, or what am I missing here?

Tags: c, warnings

The code here generates the following warning:
**Warning   C6385   Reading invalid data from 'key':  the readable size is '_Old_2`nelts' bytes, but '2' bytes may be read.**

The code compiles and runs fine. I've stepped through the code many times and see no way for next_key to step outside the array bounds.
1. Changing the union to struct makes no difference.
2. Oddly, when renaming the formal parameter to 'key', and commenting out the local 'key' and the memcpy(), no warning is generated.

```
typedef unsigned __int32  uint32_t;
typedef unsigned __int8   uint8_t;
typedef union {
    uint8_t bytes[4];
    uint32_t dword;
} quartet_t;
#define TABLE_SIZE 16
#define KEY_BUFFER_SIZE 16
uint8_t the_key[KEY_BUFFER_SIZE] = {0x2b,0x7e,0x15,0x16,0x28,0xae,0xd2,0xa6,0xab,0xf7,0x15,0x88,0x09,0xcf,0x4f,0x3c};
int job(uint8_t the_key[KEY_BUFFER_SIZE], uint32_t nelts);

int main()
{
    job(the_key, sizeof(the_key));
}

int job(uint8_t _key[KEY_BUFFER_SIZE], uint32_t nelts)
{
    int ix;
    uint32_t next_key = 0;
    quartet_t xlat[TABLE_SIZE];
    uint8_t key[KEY_BUFFER_SIZE];
    memcpy(key, _key, nelts);
    for (ix = 0; ix < TABLE_SIZE; ix++)
    {
        if (next_key == nelts)
            next_key = 0;
        xlat[ix].bytes[0] = key[next_key++];
        xlat[ix].bytes[1] = key[next_key++];
        xlat[ix].bytes[2] = key[next_key++];
        xlat[ix].bytes[3] = key[next_key++];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output is as expected, and there are no other problems. I just wish to understand if this is something I am doing wrong, or a compiler bug.

Comment: Please copy-paste the *full* and *complete* output from the build into the question, and then add a comment in the code where the warning is.

Comment: On an unrelated note, why do you `memcpy` from `_key` to `key`? Why not use `_key` directly?

Comment: @some programmer dude, the output is part of a much larger project. What I have provided here is a complete program that demonstrates the 'compiler' error I wish answered. The output is correct (but not important for this question.) On your second question, the key passed in is actually 'const', which was eliminated from this example and does not change the compiler error.

Comment: PS. the warning appears at the second assignment: xlat[ix].bytes[1] = key[next_key++];

Comment: Which tool or compiler produces this warning?

Comment: @the busybee, sorry, Visual Studio 2005, and 2019, compile for WIN32.
 an additional note on implementation. I use 'nelts' and not KEY_BUFFER_SIZE since keys may be one of 16bytes (128bit,) 24bytes(192bit,) or 32bytes (256bit.) KEY_BUFFER_SIZE is therefore defined as 32.

Comment: Regarding the `memcpy` call, unless you forgot something from your original code, there's simply no use with that in the example you show. Just pass `const uint8_t *key` and don't do the `memcpy` at all. You have a good [mcve] but it could be simplified more, like dropping that `memcpy` call. Unless it causes the warning to go away, in which case you need to explicitly point that out in the question body. And please copy-paste the full build output from the example you show, and add a comment on the line you get the warning.

Comment: Some programmer dude ... I cannot modify the caller's key because later in the code I mask it, reorder, etc....